# Is get_feature_names_out from scikit-learn SimpleImputer working?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, imputation, scikit-learn-pipeline

I'd like to access to the name of the columns that were imputed by scikit-learn `SimpleImputer` and create a DataFrame. According to documentation, it should be possible with function `get_feature_names_out`.

However, when I try the following example (taken from [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/65968/retrieve-dropped-column-names-from-sklearn-impute-simpleimputer)) it raises an error.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,np.nan,2], 'col2': [3,4,5]})

from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
si = SimpleImputer()
pd.DataFrame(si.fit_transform(data),
             columns = si.get_feature_names_out())
```

The error is:

```
AttributeError: 'SimpleImputer' object has no attribute 'get_feature_names_out'
```

Then, is there something I'm missing?

Edit:

My current scikit-learn version is: 1.0.2.

Comment: There were some bug fixes on later versions, maybe you need to update the library (works fine on V 1.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

`get_feature_names_out` became generally available in 1.1. You'll need to upgrade to get this method:

```bash
pip install scikit-learn==1.1.0
# or for latest version:
pip install --upgrade scikit-learn
```

See also: the [release notes](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/release_highlights/plot_release_highlights_1_1_0.html#get-feature-names-out-available-in-all-transformers) for scikit-learn 1.1.

---

**Workaround for older versions**. `SimpleImputer` does not change column names, so you can reuse them:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(si.fit_transform(data), columns=data.columns)
```